# Android app won't work properly when coming back to it from background

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**The Problem:**

Putting the app in background and coming back to it makes act all weird. Weird as in almost all my app features won't work. For example, when clicking on the app's multiple toolbar action buttons none of them respond. They don't do anything. No to mention the app feels slow and sluggish.

**Scenario:**

Putting the app in background and coming back to it works at times if the time interval between closing and coming back to the app is relatively short, let's say less than 30 minutes. Though I still don't know if time is the cause or is it the other apps I use in the meantime when my app is in the background.

Do you think my Nexus 5X is at fault here? I also have tried it on another phone (Samsung Galaxy A5) and the problem still persists. Or is there something wrong with my app? Any help will be appreciated.

OnResume(): (No listener is being attached here)

```
    @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // We call to set them on the outside of the if statement because another startActivity on the settings page is called when we change theme there
    // if old theme setting isn't equal to the new one: change theme cuz an update to this setting has happened
    if (mDarkTheme != mSettingsValue.getDarkTheme()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // Clears the old SettingsActivity
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    // we don't wanna call this each time onresume is called, oly when back from settings page
    if (backFromSettingsPage) {
        if (mSettingsValue == null) {
            mSettingsValue = new Settings(this);
        }

        // here we don't check if it's different but every other settings value we check if (old != new)
        mToolbarColorChange = mSettingsValue.toChangeToolbarColor();

        // Change region: this refreshes for new data
        // if old region id isn't equal to new region id
        if (mRegionId != mSettingsValue.getRegionId()) {
            mRegionId = mSettingsValue.getRegionId();
            mUpcomingGamesFragment.refresh();
        }

        boolean releasePasWeekBool = false;
        boolean releasesDuplicatesBool = false;
        // Hide/show pas week of releases
        boolean newReleasesPastWeek = mSettingsValue.toShowPastWeek();
        releasePasWeekBool = true;
        // if old != new (if value has changed)
        if (mReleasesPastWeek != newReleasesPastWeek) {
            releasePasWeekBool = true;
            // mUpcomingGamesFragment.notifyForUpdatedData();
        }

        // Hide/show Limited editions of games
        boolean removeDuplicates = mSettingsValue.getRemoveDuplicates();
        // if old != new (if value has changed) [Value has changed]
        if (mRemoveDuplicates != removeDuplicates) {
            releasesDuplicatesBool= true;
            // mUpcomingGamesFragment.notifyForUpdatedData();
        }

        if (releasePasWeekBool || releasesDuplicatesBool) {
            mUpcomingGamesFragment.refreshUpcomingList();
        }

    }
    backFromSettingsPage = false;
}
```

Comment: seems like android activity lifecycle issue. have you checked if you are doing the needful in the lifecycle methods properly like when onPause() or onResume is called?

Comment: @ruben I'm actually using onResume and what's inside is a few lines of code. What do you mean "needful" and doing it properly? Thank you!

Comment: for example if clicklistener is attached. if possible post your code, that will assist people better to answer

Comment: @ruen Good idea. I'll post my onResme()

Comment: This is default behavior of Android . What you expect ? It has to kill  unneeded processes whenever resources required . So there is enough chances that your Activity will be restart when opening from recent stack . You need to handle it .

Comment: @ADM That's not the problem. Please read the question

Comment: Already did . Reason is same ..

Comment: It does not restart the activity, but it "resumes" to the activity with everything broken, like my toolbar action items don't work